# What are each region’s state fishing records that I have to beat to unlock Old Betsy Fishing Rod?

Tags: far-cry-5

There is an achievement called

> Hope County Master Angler: Aquire all 4 fishing Rods

While the first three fishing rods are easy unlock from the store, the last rod, Old Betsy Fishing Rod, will only unlock when you "beat each region’s state records by fishing at HARD spots across Hope County".

How do I know when I have beaten a record?

Is there a list of all the records I need to beat to unlock this / What are the records I need to beat to unlock this?

Does bait matter ?

[image]

Comment: You will know if you beat the record as there will be a badge on the fish if you have beat the record on the board

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found where the records are listed after going back to Falls End (Holland Valley). Inside the Spread Eagle bar, to the left was a  board with the fish weights that I need to beat.

[image]

Thank you @Sinatar for a [source](http://gameranx.com/features/id/144413/article/far-cry-5-how-to-unlock-every-fishing-rod-master-angler-guide/) to this question:

**All Regions:**

Bull Trout: 21 lbs – Jacob’s Region, northwest of Langford Lake.

Golden Trout: 4 lbs – Jacob’s Region, west of the northern bridge entrance on Silver Lake.

Lake Trout: 37 lbs – Jacob’s Region, north of Fort Drubman in Wishbone’s Lake.

Rainbow Trout: 28 lbs – John’s Region, in the small pond southwest from Rae-Rae’s Pumpkin Farm.

**Holland Valley Region (John):**

Record board location: Inside the Spread Eagle bar in Fall's End.

Pallid Sturgeon: 55 lbs – South of the Lamb of God Church.

Paddlefish Sturgeon: 112 lbs – Far southwest of Rye & Sons Aviation, south of the southwestern-most gun shop in the region.

**Whitetail Mountain Region (Jacob):**

Record board location: In the Gun Shop in Wolf's Den.

Chinook Salmon: 27 lbs – Northwest of the F.A.N.G. Center.

Kokanee Salmon: 6 lbs – Along the southwestern shore of Cedar Lake.

Arctic Grayling Salmon: 3 lbs – High up in a pond along the southwestern border of Jacob’s Region. Check your map and look for a high pond that’s far away from civilization, near the map’s boundary.

**Henbane River Region (Faith):**

Record board location: Close to the Arcade inside Hope County Jail.

Smallmouth Bass: 6 lbs – Along the river on the eastern edge of the territory. The hard fishing spot is between two gun stores.

Largemouth Bass: 8 lbs – North of the smallmouth bass spot, on the river close to the gun store on the eastern edge of the territory.

Rock Bass: 3 lbs – Right in the center of Rock Bass Lake.

Comment: Still not sure if bait matters, but I will try testing it

Comment: There are plenty of guides already, e.g. [this one](http://gameranx.com/features/id/144413/article/far-cry-5-how-to-unlock-every-fishing-rod-master-angler-guide/). Just saying.

Comment: Do you just have to catch it, or do you turn in the prize fish somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all you have to do is catch them. The bait name applies to the name of the fish. The two that don't have names are for all kinds of fish but don't guarantee a big fish.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. It was helpful to know which bait hooks to use. Definately adds value to the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

To know whether you have beaten the record or not, check the record board in the regions. Those records that you have beaten will have a BLUE RIBBON added to them.

Comment: No need to turn in anywhere. After catching the fish above the record weight, you can immediately sell it. The record is yours as soon as you catch.